# Envers - How to propagate change of child-entity to parent?

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I've got the following setup:

```java
@Entity
@Audited
public class House {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Door frontDoor;
  
    // ...

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Audited
public class Door {

    private String color;

    // ...

}
```

and then somewhere else in my code the following lines:

```java
// #1: Creation of house
var house = new House();
var door = new Door();
door.setColor("red");
house.setFrontDoor(door);
houseRepository.save(door);

// #2: Modification of the front door
// (in another method)
var house = houseRepository.getById(/*...*/);
var door = house.getDoor();
door.setColor("blue");
houseRepository.save(house);
```

So what I get in my audit tables is something like this:

**DOOR_AUD:**

| ID | COLOR | REV | REVTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | blue | 2 | 1 |

**HOUSE_AUD:**

| ID | FRONT_DOOR | REV | REVTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

However I *need* to get a new entry in `HOUSE_AUD` as well
(like if I would modify a direct/primitive property in `house`):

| ID | FRONT_DOOR | REV | REVTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Is there any way to tell Envers to create a new Revision for all affected parents?

Answer (score 2):

So, after some research and tests, I'm here to present my results.

I encountered a similar question here on SO:
[How to Audit one-to-one relation through hibernate envers in bidirectional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495199/how-to-audit-one-to-one-relation-through-hibernate-envers-in-bidirectional)

I realized my assumption about hibernate understanding this as a parent-child relation was wrong.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55595195/9741277), `@OneToOne` even with cascading and doesn't make it a one-way directed relation.
There are several workarounds for this, I thought for feature reference I might collect them here.

### Solution I: Using an additional field

Add another field to `House` like a counter or a timestamp.

**Pro:**
This is quite a straight-forward workaround and simple to understand.

**Con:**
You'll need to make sure you update the field on every occasion when you update the `frontDoor`.
Additionally, you need to extend your database table, and the entity gets polluted with a purely technical *thing*.

### Solution II: Using Embeddable

It might be worth considering if `@OneToOne` is really the kind of relation you want to express. Maybe `Door` would be better suited as an `@Embeddable`.

**Pro:** You don't need to care for anything else.

**Con:** If `Door` would contain itself `@Embedded` fields, this might simply be no option. Also, you might use `Door` already in a different context where you need it to be a separate entity.

### Solution III: Using Conditional Auditing

Didn't try or saw anyone doing this, but it might work ...

### Solution IV: Change your approach to auditing

Maybe you can rethink your usage of the audit stuff and check (recursively?) for revisions in sub-entites when you need to get a list of all the different versions.

---

Hopefully, the Hibernate Team will address this in the future. However, it doesn't look too promising: [HHH-13362](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13362)